# Trying to develop a CoffeeScript Singleton Fetcher

Tags: coffeescript, singleton

I'm trying to develop a CoffeeScript Singleton Fetcher based on an idea represented in the [CoffeeScript Cookbook](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/design_patterns/singleton).

The cookbook describes how to implement a singlelton class in CoffeeScript and how to fetch that class from the global namespace, like so:

```
root = exports ? this

# The publicly accessible Singleton fetcher
class root.Singleton
  _instance = undefined # Must be declared here to force the closure on the class
  @get: (args) -> # Must be a static method
    _instance ?= new _Singleton args

# The actual Singleton class
class _Singleton
  constructor: (@args) ->

  echo: ->
    @args

a = root.Singleton.get 'Hello A'
a.echo()
# => 'Hello A'
```

**What I am trying to develop**

I'm trying to develop a way to to fetch many singlton classes from the root.Singleton object. Like so:

```
root = exports ? this 

# The publicly accessible Singleton fetcher
class root.Singleton
  _instance = undefined # Must be declared here to force the closure on the class
  @get: (args, name) -> # Must be a static method
    switch name
      when 'Singleton1' then _instance ?= new Singleton1 args
      when 'Singleton2' then _instance ?= new Singleton2 args
      else console.log 'ERROR: Singleton does not exist'


# The actual Singleton class
class Singleton1
  constructor: (@args) ->

  echo: ->
    console.log @args

class Singleton2
  constructor: (@args) ->

  echo: ->
    console.log @args

a = root.Singleton.get 'Hello A', 'Singleton1'
a.echo()
# => 'Hello A'

b = root.Singleton.get 'Hello B', 'Singleton2'
b.echo()
# => 'Hello B'
```

The goal is to get a singleton by declaring:

```
root.Singleton 'Constructor Args' 'Singleton name'
```

**The Problem**

Unfortunately a.echo() and b.echo() both print 'Hello A', they are both referencing the same Singleton.

**The Question**

Where am I going wrong? How can I develop a simple Singleton fetcher like I describe above?

Comment: So this is effectively a "Singleton Factory" then?

Comment: Yes, I can't find any good implementations of Singleton Factories for CoffeeScript on the net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see you are overwriting your "single" instance.
So you need at least some container to hold your "many" singletons and
to access them later on.

```
class root.Singleton
    @singletons = 
        Singleton1: Singleton1
        Singleton2: Singleton2
    @instances = {}
    @get: (name, args...) -> # Must be a static method
        @instances[name] ||= new @singletons[name] args...
```

What you call a "fetcher" is a factory pattern.

Comment: Your `@get` could be just `@instances[name] ||= new @singletons[name] args...`, no? You could also change `@get` to `@get: (name, args...)` to get a more natural (IMO) interface. All that's just nit picking though :)

Answer (score 1):

thanks for nice example around `@args` / `args...` and singleton.

just for a newbie in CoffeeScript like me, in this example we need to change the calling order (`args...` to the end):

```
a = root.Singleton.get 'Singleton1', 'Hello A'
a.echo()
# => 'Hello A'

b = root.Singleton.get 'Singleton2', 'Hello B'
b.echo()
# => 'Hello B'
```